# tcng - match port range in "if" statement

Tags: linux, controls, range, traffic

Hi I need to match a specified port range (say from 16384 to 32768) with tcng in order to give traffic outgoing from this ports an higher priority.

Example file:

```
#include "fields.tc"
dev "eth0" {
    egress {
        class(<$voip>) if ip_proto == IPPROTO_UDP && udp_sport == ...;
        class(<$other>) if 1;
        prio {
            $voip = class(1) {
                fifo();
            }
            $other = class(2) {
                fifo();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a simple "udp_sport >= 16384 && udp_sport <= 32768" works.
at least in tcng version 10b.
so write it like this:

```
#include "fields.tc"
dev "eth0" {
    egress {
        class(<$voip>) if ip_proto == IPPROTO_UDP && udp_sport >= 16384 && udp_sport <= 32768;
        class(<$other>) if 1;
        prio {
            $voip = class(1) {
                fifo();
            }
            $other = class(2) {
                fifo();
            }
        }
    }
}
```